# Как можно сделать чтоб программа вернулось к методу main.(повторилось)?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = getInt();
        int num2 = getInt();
        char operation = getOperation();
        int result = calc(num1,num2,operation);
        System.out.println("Результат операции: "+result);
    }

    public static int getInt(){
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        int num;
        if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            num = scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа. Попробуйте еще раз.");
            scanner.next();//рекурсия
            num = getInt();
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static char getOperation(){
        System.out.println("Введите операцию:");
        char operation;
        if(scanner.hasNext()){
            operation = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе операции. Попробуйте еще раз.");
            scanner.next();//рекурсия
            operation = getOperation();
        }
        return operation;
    }

    public static int calc(int num1, int num2, char operation){
        int result;
        switch (operation){
            case '+':
                result = num1+num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1-num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1*num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = num1/num2;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Операция не распознана. Повторите ввод.");
                result = calc(num1, num2, getOperation());//рекурсия
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Обернуть кусок, который требуется повторять, в `while(условие-при-котором-повторять)`

Comment: можоте  помоч мне в етом?

Comment: кто-то  может помоч розобратсья в  етом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
public class Calculator {
    ...

    static boolean have_task = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // как уже было сказано в комментарии,
        // нужно поставить цикл над кодом, который должен повторяться
        while (have_task) {

            // и такой функционал полезно выносить в отдельные функции/методы
            process();

            // также нужно добавить правило,
            // по которому делать have_task = false
            // чтобы можно было выйти из программы
        }
    }

    public static void process() {
        int num1 = getInt();
        int num2 = getInt();
        char operation = getOperation();
        int result = calc(num1,num2,operation);
        System.out.println("Результат операции: "+result);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: всем большое  спосибо

Comment: @MherBalayan благодарности на этом сайте выражают стрелочкой вверх и галкой принятого ответа ;)